# How to create a Spring roo web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

I am new to Spring and Spring roo..

I reffered this link. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html
but it is not working for me. 
Could anyone please give a step by step guidance to create a simple spring roo web app project using Spring tools suite 3.4.0.

Thanks in advance,
Vibin.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open STS
2. Click File->New->Other
3. Select Spring -> Spring Roo Project
4. Set a name, click finish
5. After roo console has loaded, follow these steps:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html?beginning-step-1

Answer (score 1):

You can do what Stefan has said and do the following from roo console.

The following worked for me.
You can do the following in console. Roo will create a new project and you can import it into STS. Lifted from 
http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

```
mkdir hello
cd hello
roo
roo> hint
roo> project --topLevelPackage com.foo
roo> jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY         
roo> entity jpa --class ~.Timer --testAutomatically
roo> field string --fieldName message --notNull
roo> hint web mvc
roo> web mvc setup
roo> web mvc all --package ~.web
roo> selenium test --controller ~.web.TimerController
roo> web gwt setup
roo> web gwt all --proxyPackage ~.client.proxy --requestPackage ~.client.request          
roo> perform tests
roo> quit
```